# Refactor across two Java projects in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Suppose there is Maven Project A and Maven Project B. Project B has defined a dependency on A in its pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Now open both projects in IntelliJ idea (two separate windows).

What is the best way to refactor a method in project A?

Currently I do the refactoring in A and call "mvn install" for it, then do search&replace in project B and this works okayish. But is there something faster? In NetBeans I just open both projects and the refactoring will be applied to all open projects.

Comment: This might be the answer: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206984715-Using-IDEA-to-refactor-a-multi-project-dependency- ... will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is it import the parent Maven `pom.xml` which defines the dependencies between the modules. This way you will have both modules open in IntelliJ IDEA at the same time and the refactorings will work across the project.

Comment: You mean the answer suggested here? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206984715-Using-IDEA-to-refactor-a-multi-project-dependency-
Isn't there a less cumbersome solution?

Comment: It's the most natural and appropriate solution for this case.

Comment: If you find this natural you haven't used NetBeans ;D